# Should ciabatta sandwich rolls be dry and dense?

Tags: bread

I found a recipe calling for ciabatta sandwich rolls. My supermarket sells these, baked in their bakery, however, I found this bread dry and dense, which I do not find appealing. Should this kind of bread have this quality?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ciabatta should be crusty, with a chewy crumb and big air pockets. Neither "dry" nor "dense" would be adjectives one would associate with good ciabatta.

This is what good ciabatta should look like:

[image: 1]
Source: [Michael Ruhlman](http://ruhlman.com/2011/01/ciabatta-recipe/) (highly respected recipe and author)

Sometimes the loaves may be flatter, but the chewiness, big air pockets, and crustiness are what define good ciabatta.

[image: 2]
Source: [Brown Eyed Baker](http://www.browneyedbaker.com/ciabatta-bread/)

If you can't find good ciabatta at your store, would you consider making your own? Both of the above links have highly regarded recipes. The Brown Eyed Baker link will lead you to the same recipe as in the video I'm about to mention.

I have had great luck with [America's Test Kitchen](http://www.americastestkitchen.com/)'s ciabatta recipe and video, but it only shows the forming of loaves, not rolls. This [recipe](http://www.cookstr.com/recipes/ciabatta-rolls) describes a method for shaping ciabatta rolls. I really appreciated the video since I had never before dealt with a dough so "wet" (80% hydration, nearly pourable). ATK offers a 14 day free trial, so I'd recommend trying it and checking out that video. These pictures are from my first ciabatta from ATK's recipe:

[image: 3][image: 4][image: 5]

I was very pleased, I followed every little fussy step in the video. That broke it down into manageable chunks, and made it seem easy.